# wordpress index.php not showing up

Tags: php, html, wordpress, redirect

I want to re-do a website using Wordpress. Since I don't feel confident in developing it somewhere else then moving it to the server once completed, I've moved the actual website on a subdir, put a **`index.html`** file containing just a redirect on the root, then installed wordpress.

Plan is: visitors just calling the url will get **`index.html`**, so will be redirected to the old website in the subdir, while I should be able to call **`url+index.php`** to check the wp website in development (since html has priority over php).

Once website will be completed, I'll remove the **`index.html`** file performing the redirect and visitors should start viewing the new website.

Problem is: even when calling **`url/index.php`** I'm redirected as if I had not added the specific request to **`index.php`** file.

Any help?

Comment: Can you add the contents of `index.php` and `.htaccess` file if present in that dir?

Comment: Sure. They're "vanilla" index and htaccess by WP installation

EDIT: unable to add file content. Formatting gets wrecked. Also char count prevents me to add whole files contents.